# JQgrid inline editing with asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I am using above below for viewing data and editing with it. First row is used for edit button, but whenever I click save button I am unable to capture that event.

I want to know how it works and how can I call a AJAX function to store that data to SQL Server.

```
$(function() {
    var grid_selector = "#grid-table-Labor";

    $("#grid-table-Labor").jqGrid({
        url: 'LaborApproval.aspx/GetLaborData', //asp function to get all data from data base to grid 
        data: "{}",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        serializeGridData: function(postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },
        ajaxGridOptions: {
            contentType: "application/json"
        },
        loadonce: true,
        colNames: [' ', 'Employee Code', 'Name', 'Contractor', 'DOJ', 'Police Verification', 'Gate Pass Valid Upto', 'Status', 'Remark'],
        colModel: [{
                name: 'myac',
                index: 'myac',
                width: 80,
                fixed: true,
                sortable: false,
                resize: false,
                formatter: 'actions',
                formatoptions: {
                    keys: true,
                    delbutton: false, //disable delete button

                    //delOptions: { recreateForm: true, beforeShowForm: beforeDeleteCallback },
                    //editformbutton:true                                              
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'EMPCODE',
                index: 'EMPCODE',
                width: 108,
                formatter: 'showlink',
                key: true
            },
            {
                name: 'NAME',
                index: 'NAME',
                width: 140
            },
            {
                name: 'CONTNAME',
                index: 'CONTNAME',
                width: 160
            },
            {
                name: 'DOJ',
                index: 'DOJ',
                width: 70,
                formatter: 'date',
                formatoptions: {
                    newformat: 'd-m-y'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'POLICE_VRIFICATION',
                index: 'POLICE_VRIFICATION',
                width: 124
            },
            {
                name: 'GatePassValidUpto',
                index: 'GatePassValidUpto',
                editable: true,
                sorttype: "date",
                unformat: pickDate
            },
            {
                name: 'Approve',
                index: 'Approve',
                width: 148,
                editable: true,
                edittype: "select",
                editoptions: {
                    value: "1:Approve;0:Rejected"
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'REMARK',
                index: 'REMARK',
                width: 150,
                sortable: false,
                editable: true,
                edittype: "textarea",
                editoptions: {
                    rows: "2",
                    cols: "10"
                }
            }
        ],
        pager: '#grid-pager-Labor',
        altRows: true,
        cacheUrlData: true,
        //toppager: true,
        rowNum: 1,
        scrollOffset: 0, // to remove offset of scroll bar for imporved gui
        rowList: [10, 50, 100, 200, 300, 500, 800, 1000, 1500],
        //onSelectRow: editRow,
        viewrecords: true,
        emptyrecords: "Nothing to display",
        //multiselect: true,
        //multiboxonly: false,
        gridview: true,
        loadComplete: function() {
            var table = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                //styleCheckbox(table);
                //updateActionIcons(table);
                updatePagerIcons(table);
                enableTooltips(table);
            }, 0);
        },
        jsonReader: {
            page: function(obj) {
                return 1;
            },
            total: function(obj) {
                return 1;
            },
            records: function(obj) {
                return obj.d.length;
            },
            root: function(obj) {
                return obj.d;
            },
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "0"
        },

        //editurl: "LaborApproval.aspx/PostLaborData",
        editurl: "",
        caption: 'Labor List',
        shrinkToFit: true,
        height: 'auto',
        //autowidth: true,
    });


    $('#grid-table-Labor').jqGrid('navGrid', '#grid-pager-Labor', {
        edit: false,
        del: false,
        search: true,
        searchtext: "Search",
        searchicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search orange',
        view: true,
        viewtext: "View",
        viewicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search-plus grey',
    })
});

function updatePagerIcons(table) {
    var replacement = {
        'ui-icon-seek-first': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left bigger-140',
        'ui-icon-seek-prev': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-left bigger-140',
        'ui-icon-seek-next': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-right bigger-140',
        'ui-icon-seek-end': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right bigger-140'
    };
    $('.ui-pg-table:not(.navtable) > tbody > tr > .ui-pg-button > .ui-icon').each(function() {
        var icon = $(this);
        var $class = $.trim(icon.attr('class').replace('ui-icon', ''));
        if ($class in replacement) icon.attr('class', 'ui-icon ' + replacement[$class]);
    })
}

function enableTooltips(table) {
    $('.navtable .ui-pg-button').tooltip({
        container: 'body'
    });
    $(table).find('.ui-pg-div').tooltip({
        container: 'body'
    });
}

function pickDate(cellvalue, options, cell) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(cell).find('input[type=text]')
            .datepicker({
                format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                autoclose: true
            });
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used following code to complete my task

```
          $(function () {

            var grid_selector = "#grid-table-Labor";

            $("#grid-table-Labor").jqGrid({
                url: 'LaborApproval.aspx/GetLaborData', //asp function to get all data from data base to grid 
                data: "{}",
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'POST',
                serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                    return JSON.stringify(postData);
                },
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                loadonce: true,
                colNames: [' ', 'Worker Code', 'Name', 'Contractor', 'DOJ', 'Police Verification', 'Gate Pass Valid Upto', 'Status', 'Remark'],
                colModel: [
                                {
                                    name: 'myac', index: 'myac', width: 80, fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false, formatter: 'actions',
                                    formatoptions: {
                                        keys: true,
                                        delbutton: false,
                                        editOptions: {},
                                        addOptions: {},
                                        delOptions: {}
                                    }
                                },
                                { name: 'EMPCODE', index: 'EMPCODE', width: 108, formatter:fontColorFormat, key: true },
                                { name: 'NAME', index: 'NAME', width: 140 },
                                { name: 'CONTNAME', index: 'CONTNAME', width: 160 },
                                { name: 'DOJ', index: 'DOJ', width: 70, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-m-y' } },
                                { name: 'POLICE_VRIFICATION', index: 'POLICE_VRIFICATION', width: 124 },
                                { name: 'GatePassValidUpto', index: 'GatePassValidUpto', editable: true, sorttype: "date", formatter: 'date', unformat: pickDate, formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-m-Y' } },
                                { name: 'Approve', index: 'Approve', width: 148, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "True:Approve;False:Reject" } },
                                { name: 'REMARK', index: 'REMARK', width: 150, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: "textarea", editoptions: { rows: "2", cols: "10" } }
                ],
                pager: '#grid-pager-Labor',
                altRows: true,
                //cacheUrlData: true,
                //toppager: true,
                rowNum: 10,
                scrollOffset: 0, // to remove offset of scroll bar for imporved gui
                rowList: [10, 50, 100, 200, 300, 500, 800, 1000, 1500],
                //onSelectRow: editRow,
                viewrecords: true,
                emptyrecords: "Nothing to display",
                //multiselect: true,
                //multiboxonly: false,
                gridview: true,
                loadComplete: function () {
                    var table = this;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        //styleCheckbox(table);
                        //updateActionIcons(table);
                        updatePagerIcons(table);
                        enableTooltips(table);
                    }, 0);
                },
                jsonReader: {
                    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                    records: function (obj) { return obj.d.length; },
                    root: function (obj) { return obj.d; },
                    repeatitems: false,
                    id: "0"
                },                    
                editurl: '../../Handler/JQGridHRHandler.ashx',
                caption: 'Labor List',
                shrinkToFit: true,
                height: 'auto',
                //autowidth: true,
                xmlReader: {
                    root: "list",
                    row: "Response",
                    id: "cfgId",
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e)
                {
                    var href = '../Tab_Pages/EmployeeTab.aspx?empcode=' + rowid;
                    window.open(href);
                    return false;                            

                    //var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest("td")[0]);
                    //if (this.p.colModel[iCol].name === 'EMPCODE') {                                                       
                    //    var param = { param: rowid };

                    //    console.log(rowid);
                    //    $.ajax({
                    //        url: "LaborApproval.aspx/ShowMe",                                
                    //        data: JSON.stringify(param),
                    //        dataType: "json",
                    //        type: "POST",
                    //        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                         
                    //        success: function (data) {
                    //            console.log(data);                                                                            
                    //                    var box = bootbox.dialog({
                    //                            show: true,
                    //                            message: data['d'],
                    //                            title: "Labour Details",
                    //                            buttons: {
                    //                                ok: {
                    //                                    label: "OK",
                    //                                    className: "btn-primary",
                    //                                    callback: function() {
                    //                                        console.log('OK Button');
                    //                                    }
                    //                                }                                   
                    //                            }
                    //                    });
                    //                    box.modal('show');
                    //                },
                    //        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //            var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
                    //            alert(err.Message)
                    //            // console.log("Ajax Error!");  
                    //        }
                    //    });

                    //    return false;
                    //}
                }
            });



            $('#grid-table-Labor').jqGrid('navGrid', '#grid-pager-Labor',
                {
                    edit: false,
                    del: false,
                    search: true,
                    searchtext: "Search",
                    searchicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search orange',
                    view: true,
                    viewtext: "View",
                    viewicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-search-plus grey',
                },
                {   //EDIT portion
                    //Can also set the width and height of the editing window as below commented way 
                    //height: 300,
                    //width: 400,
                    //top: 50,
                    //left: 100,
                    //dataheight: 280,
                    closeOnEscape: true,//Closes the popup on pressing escape key
                    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                    drag: true,
                    afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                        if (response.responseText == "") {
                            $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam',
                              { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');//Reloads the grid after edit
                            return [true, '']
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam',
                              { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid'); //Reloads the grid after edit
                            return [false, response.responseText]
                            //Captures and displays the response text on th Edit window
                        }
                    },
                    editData: {
                        EmpId: function () {
                            var sel_id = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                            var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
                            return value;
                        }
                    }
                })
        });

        function updatePagerIcons(table) {
            var replacement =
            {
                'ui-icon-seek-first': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left bigger-140',
                'ui-icon-seek-prev': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-left bigger-140',
                'ui-icon-seek-next': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-right bigger-140',
                'ui-icon-seek-end': 'ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right bigger-140'
            };
            $('.ui-pg-table:not(.navtable) > tbody > tr > .ui-pg-button > .ui-icon').each(function () {
                var icon = $(this);
                var $class = $.trim(icon.attr('class').replace('ui-icon', ''));
                if ($class in replacement) icon.attr('class', 'ui-icon ' + replacement[$class]);
            })
        }

        function enableTooltips(table) {
            $('.navtable .ui-pg-button').tooltip({ container: 'body' });
            $(table).find('.ui-pg-div').tooltip({ container: 'body' });
        }

        function pickDate(cellvalue, options, cell) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(cell).find('input[type=text]')
                    .datepicker({ format: 'dd-mm-yyyy', autoclose: true });
            }, 0);
        }
        var lastSelection;

        function fontColorFormat(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            var color = "blue";
            var cellHtml = "<span style='color:" + color + "' originalValue='" + cellvalue + "'>" + cellvalue + "</span>";
            return cellHtml;
        }

        function editRow(id) {
            if (id && id !== lastSelection) {
                var grid = $("#grid-table-Labor");
                grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelection);
                grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, { keys: true, focusField: 5 });
                lastSelection = id;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note which version of jqGrid is used.
If you use [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) you may need to use serializeRowData described in our [documentation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#inline-editing) the same  you use serializeGridData to get parameters from the grid.

Kind Regards

Comment: I am using jqGrid JS - v5.0.2

Comment: You use Guriddo jqGrid. Can you please use the serializeRowData as described from me in previous post?

Comment: Please look at the documentation link, provided from me. The event is a grid event and you should it maybe use the same way as the serilizeGridData the code should be like this: `$("#grid").jqGrid({..., serializeRowData : function (data){ return JSON.stringify(postData); },...}); ` Look at the docs : what is posted to the server when save the data